# Help me parse a text file and extract specific values

Tags: f#

I have a file called `lijst.txt`. The file is an output from a printmessage eventlog file.
All the lines have the same format.
I want to extract from each line the username, which is between the words `owned by` and `was`. Also, I want to extract the pagecount, which is between the words `pages printed:` and `.`.  I would like to put these values in a new text file.

Regards,

Dennis (new in F#)

Comment: A sample input data would help a lot here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using a regular expression for this, something like:

```
open System.Text.RegularExpressions

let usernameRegex = new Regex(".*owned by\s+(?<username>.*)\s+was.*")

/// Trys to extract the username from a given line of text. Returns None if the line is malformed
// Note: You could also use failwith in the else branch or throw an exception or ...
let extractUsername line = 
    let regexMatch = usernameRegex.Match(line) in
    if regexMatch.Success then Some regexMatch.Groups.["username"].Value else None

// In reality you would like to load this from file using File.ReadAllLines
let sampleLines = 
    ["Some text some text owned by DESIRED USERNAME was some text some text";
     "Some text line not containing the pattern";
     "Another line owned by ANOTHER USER was"]

let extractUsernames lines = 
    lines
    |> Seq.map extractUsername
    |> Seq.filter (fun usernameOption -> usernameOption.IsSome)
    |> Seq.map (fun usernameOption -> usernameOption.Value)

// You can now save the usernames to a file using 
// File.WriteAllLines("FileName", extractUsernames(sampleLines))
```

Comment: Hi , thanx for the awnser . its part of the solution but i think i can manage to sort de usernames and get the printed pages per user (i think) Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
let getBetween (a:string) (b:string) (str:string) = 
        str.Split(a.ToCharArray()).[1].Split(b.ToCharArray()).[0].Trim()  

let total (a:string seq) =
    (a |> Seq.map Int32.Parse |> Seq.reduce (+)).ToString()

File.ReadAllLines("inFile") |> Seq.map (fun l -> (getBetween "owned by" "was" l , getBetween "Pages printed:" "." l) )
|> Seq.groupBy (fun (user,count) -> user)
|> Seq.map (fun (user,counts) -> user + "\t" + (counts |> Seq.map snd |> total) )
|> (fun s -> File.WriteAllLines("outFile",s) )
```

Comment: How to put for each user the total page count into one txtfile ??

Comment: I have updated my answer, please try that. This will put the user and count in each line and user and count is separated by tab

Comment: Hi , thx for tthe code but i got a lot of error System.formatexeption: inputstring was not in the correct format

Comment: Seems that parseInt is not working because the string between pages printed\\: and . is not an integer

Comment: between those words it's always a number . like pages printed: 6. No user action is required. It's standard message from log event 10

Comment: Can u post sample data from the input file ?

Comment: "Document 201, Microsoft Word - WOENSDAG 15 JUNI 2011 INCIDENT LAUREEN.doc owned by User was printed on 12825 through port IP_Number.  Size in bytes: 411836. Pages printed: 2. No user action is required. -- this is for every line--

Comment: The page count is after "Pages printed:" and not "pages printed\:" as you have mentioned in your question. I have updated my code, try that

Comment: unfortely that's not the probleem ,